# How to copy a sheet with polish letter in name [VBA]?

Tags: excel, vba, special-characters, worksheet, polish

I need to copy sheet from one workbook to another workbook. That is simple, but name of this sheet contains a polish letter "ł".

I know I have to replace "ł" with " & ChrW$(&H142) & ", but have no idea how to build a name of sheet that VBA will find.

Let say that the name of sheet that I want to copy is "masło"

Part of code should be

```
x.Sheets("masło").Copy After:=y.Sheets("examplesheetname")
```

How do I write the word 'masło' so that VBA finds that unfortunate 'ł'?

Comment: Have you tried `Sheets("mas" & ChrW$(&H142) & "o")`?

Comment: After that appear 

Run time error '1004'

Comment: It works for me, what's the error message?

Comment: Path not found: '.\VBE87F.tmp'

Comment: @adam_m in which line do you get this error? Because it cannot be from the line of code you show in your question. What exactly is `x` and `y` probably there is something wrong.

Comment: I set x as activeworkbook and y as thisworkbook - as below:

`Dim y As Workbook

'wybierz plik z którego będą kopiowane dane
Dim x As Variant
x = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")
    If x <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=x
    End If
    
Set x = ActiveWorkbook
Set y = ThisWorkbook

'here you can find a seeking code line
x.Sheets("mas" & ChrW$(&H142) & "o").Copy After:=x.Sheets("ceny 2020")

x.close
End Sub`

The error appear in this particular line with searching for a sheet name "masło" :)